# Google Street View on iOS is failed to load and block all http request

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

For the first few times to load the street view page, it doesn't have any problem.

Around 3-4 times go back and enter the street view page, the street view is loading forever without any error message.

Then I go to another page, the connectivity lost forever, even AdMob also can not show up any ads.
The app is totally isolated. After killing the app, everything goes normal again.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?
Thanks

```
// street view
    let panoramaNear = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(map_x, map_y)
    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView.panoramaWithFrame(CGRectZero, nearCoordinate:panoramaNear)
    panoView.camera = GMSPanoramaCamera.init(heading: map_heading, pitch: map_pitch, zoom: 1, FOV: map_fov)
    self.view = panoView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what's wrong, it's because of the AdMob interstitial ads. I request the streetview and admob interstitial simultaneously. Maybe it is a bug? So I removed the interstitial request, then everything works again.